# how to stop for sending multiple email's

Tags: php, email, codeigniter

i am working in codeigniter.
I have mistakenly sending a bulk of email while testing ..

My problem is that i am testing to send multiple email's in a `while loop` but mistakenly the `loop become infinity`
So now i receive email's again and again

How can i stop these email.
Please any suggestion.

Comment: Was my answer insufficient? Are you still having this trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop loading the page and wait. PHP hosts have a time limit on a script before the process is killed. If you're running this as localhost, restart your apache server.